Problem with Dynamic Meta Tags for Social Media Sharing
I’m working on a project where I dynamically update meta tags based on data fetched from an API. While this works for updating the meta content on the page, the changes do not reflect when the page is shared on social media platforms.
Scenario:

I have a game details page where clicking on a review opens a modal with detailed information about the review.
When a review is clicked, I also update the meta tags () to reflect the review’s details (e.g., title, description, image).
However, when sharing the link to this page on social media (e.g., Facebook, Twitter), the preview still shows the original meta content rather than the updated content.


These systems typically have a pretty long cache. I'm not sure if there's a way to force a new lookup, but one potential solution might be to bust the cache by slightly altering the URL after each change.
